# why this program to remove all comments doesn't worked?

Tags: c, arrays

**this is my 21 trial really i can't find where should i search , the following code is to remove single comment line** 
i'm using buffer to collect all data then i tried to filer them but i suspect on line inside if statement

```
 if(arr[pos] == '/' &&  arr[pos+1] == '/')
```

but i can't find difference till now
this is the whole code

```
#define         MAXSIZE         200
#define         ON              1
#define         OFF             0

char uncomentedBuffer[MAXSIZE];
char Buffer[MAXSIZE];
char comment[MAXSIZE];
void uncommen(char *arr);
//int getLine(char *arr, int lim);
int main(void)
{
    int c, pos = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        Buffer[pos] = c;
        pos++;
    }
    uncommen(Buffer);
    printf("%s",uncomentedBuffer);
    return 0;
}

void uncommen(char *arr)
{
    int pos = 0 ,nBS = 0, nAS = 0 ,scomment = OFF, bcomment = OFF;
    while(pos <= MAXSIZE )
    {
        if(arr[pos] == '/' &&  arr[pos+1] == '/')
        {
            scomment = ON;
            while(scomment == ON && arr[pos] != '\n')
            {
                pos++;
            }
            scomment = OFF;
        }
        uncomentedBuffer[pos] = arr[pos];
        pos++;
    }
}
```

i need help

Comment: You should also post an input file for which the program doesn't work as expected

Comment: I design it to read from stream

Comment: Not the problem, but you're missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: `f(arr[pos] == '/' &&  arr[pos+1] == '/')` you access invalid locations beyond the array when `pos` is `MAXSIZE - 1` and `MAXSIZE`

Comment: Here's the issue: `uncomentedBuffer[pos] = arr[pos];`. Use another variable for indexing `uncomentedBuffer`

Comment: What output you get for sample input **abcd//ade**? I received correct output **abcd**

Comment: Perhaps reading the file with `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) for a *line-oriented* approach to the read would simplify things....

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: The main error has been found, but here is another error: Your input may be smaller than MAXSIZE, but you always go through the whole of `Buffer`, which will give you random output after the correctly processed text. You should also stop reading input when `Buffer` is filled.

Comment: What do you mean by *"single comment line"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your uncomented string is initialized with a bunch of `'\0'` (*nul-characters*), which signals the end of the string. Your are ignoring a commented position of the input string, and leaving a bunch of `'\0'` behind.

A solution would be to create a specific counter to avoid leaving trash in the uncomented string:

```
void uncommen(char *arr) 
{
    int pos = 0, auxPos = 0 ,nBS = 0, nAS = 0 ,scomment = OFF, bcomment = OFF;
    while(pos <= MAXSIZE )
    {
        if(arr[pos] == '/' &&  arr[pos+1] == '/')
        {
            scomment = ON;
            while(scomment == ON && arr[pos] != '\n')
            {
                pos++;
            }
            scomment = OFF;
        }
        uncomentedBuffer[auxPos] = arr[pos];
        pos++;
        auxPos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree... But also notice that a) `(pos <= MAXSIZE )` is wrong. Should be `(pos < MAXSIZE-1 )` and b) `scomment` isn't needed at all and c) the inner loop may cause an infinite loop if last line is a comment with no newline. It should be more like `while(pos < MAXSIZE && arr[pos] != '\n')` and d) there are a number of unused variables